# Use "fgetc" to find lowest value for the sum of RGB (0) from PPM file in C programing?

Tags: c

I have a assignment which need to find the "lowest value " for the sum of RGB(0,0,0) from a PPM file using "fgetc" or other variable. I'm completely lost on what I'm supposed to do. Need some help.

The following is the code I wrote so far:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char* filename = argv[1];
    image = readPPM("abc.ppm");
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Problems I see:

1. `img` is not initialized at all. It is used before it is assigned to point to a valid `PPMImage`. That causes the line:

   `n=img->x * img->y;`

   to cause segmentation violation.
2. `fgets` returns a `char*`. In the line

   `int a = fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp);`

   you are assigning a `char*` to an `int`.
3. You have

   ```
   **int i,j,array[n];
   ch = array[0];

   for (i=1;i<n;i++)
   {
       if(ch<array[i])
       ch = array[i];
   }**
   ```

   The `**`s at the start of the block and at the end of the block were unexpected. I am not sure what you were thinking.

The last two problems are minor ones. If you fix the first problem, things might work.

Here's a reworked `PPMInage`

```
static PPMImage *readPPM(const char *filename)
{
   char buff[16];
   PPMImage *img;
   FILE *fp;
   int n;
   int maxRGB;
   int red;
   int green;
   int blue;
   int i;
   int sum;
   int minSum;

   //open PPM file for reading
   if((fp=fopen(filename,"rb"))==NULL){
       printf("Can't open file: %s \n",filename);
   }
   else{
       printf("image name: %s \n",filename);
   }

   //read image format
   if (!fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp)) {
       perror(filename);
       exit(1);
   }

   //check the image format
   if (buff[0] != 'P' || buff[1] != '3') {
       printf("Invalid image format (must be 'P3')\n");
       exit(1);
   }
   else{
       printf("magic number  = P3 \n");
   }

   // Allocate memory for the image.
   img = malloc(sizeof(PPMImage));

   // Read the X and Y dimensions of the image.
   fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &(img->x), &(img->y));

   // Allocate memory for the pixel data.
   n=img->x * img->y;
   img->data = malloc(n*sizeof(pixel_t));

   // Read the max RGB value and discard.
   // We don't need it.
   fscanf(fp, "%d", &maxRGB);

   // Read the RGB values one by one.
   for ( i = 0; i < n; ++i )
   {
      if ( fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &red, &green, &blue) != 3 )
      {
         printf("Incomplete RGB data\n");
         return img;
      }

      img->data[i].red = (unsigned char)red;
      img->data[i].green = (unsigned char)green;
      img->data[i].blue = (unsigned char)blue;
   }

   // Get the minimum sum.
   minSum = img->data[0].red + img->data[0].green + img->data[0].blue;
   for ( i = 1; i < n; ++i )
   {
      sum = img->data[i].red + img->data[i].green + img->data[i].blue;
      if ( minSum > sum )
      {
         minSum = sum;
      }
   }

   printf("Minimum RGB sum: %d\n", minSum);

   return img;
}
```

Comment: sorry, **int i,j,array[n];
ch = array[0];

for (i=1;i<n;i++)
{
    if(ch<array[i])
    ch = array[i];
}** 
 I want to bold these words, to let people know this is my problem is!

Comment: Any ideas of how to find the lowest value for the sum of RGB (0) from PPM file?

Comment: a note on "img is initialized to NULL", I don't see it initialized anywhere.

Comment: @BuellaGábor Good eyes. I noticed the value of `NULL` when I ran the program and assumed it was initialized to `NULL`. I fixed my answer to correct that statement.

Comment: Also, based on OP's comment here, OP might be a bot, or just really not satisfied with your answer.

Comment: @user3435575 In addition to tracking the minimum value, you can also track the index where the minimum value occurs.

Comment: @user3435575 I think you have enough guidance to finish this programming task by yourself. I feel that I will be doing you a disservice if I help you any further.